# 2000 honda civic dx transmission gears

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, civic

So I recently changed the shifter cable. Problem is now when car is in park it's actually in neutral. I've adjusted the bolt and have turned the shift thing on the tranmission itself all the way to park and still I am experiencing this issue. Could it be the transmission itself? I didn't have the problem prior to changing the shift cable. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It has obviously been adjusted correctly, since my previous question has been removed.